# grunt-contrib-connect running but not working

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect

```
"grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
```

After run: **grunt connect**

```
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:8000

Done.
```

[image]

So when I check in my browser: localhost:8000 , does not open anything.

can someone help on this?

gruntfile pastenbin : http://pastebin.com/nL771d5j

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function  (grunt) {
    var config = {};

    //setup the configuration object
    var jshint;

    //all tasks that must be loaded.
    var tasks = [
            ,'grunt-contrib-watch'
            ,'grunt-contrib-concat'
            ,'grunt-contrib-sass'
            ,'grunt-contrib-connect'
    ];

                //src ===============================
                var src;
                config.src = src = {
                     sassMain        : 'scss/main.scss',
                     distFolder      : 'public/stylesheets/dist.css',
                     devFolder       : 'public/stylesheets/dev.css',
                     sassFolder      : 'scss/**/*.scss',
                     serverPort: 9000,
                     serverHost: '0.0.0.0' 
                };


                //Concat ===============================

                var concat
                config.concat = concat = {};

                concat.dev = {
                    files: {
                        "public/myapp.development.js": [
                            "with-bootstrap/public/js/vendor"
                            ,"with-bootstrap/public/js/**/*.js"
                        ]
                    }
                };

                //Watch ===============================
                config.watch = {
                     scripts: {
                        files: ["<%= src.sassFolder %>"]
                        ,tasks: ["sass:dist"]
                     }
                }

                //Sass ===============================
                var sass;
                config.sass = sass = {};

                    //distribution
                        sass.dist = {
                            options: { 
                                style: "compressed",
                                noCache: true, 
                                sourcemap: 'none', 
                                update:true
                            }
                            , files: {
                                "<%= src.distFolder %>" : "<%= src.sassMain %>"
                            }
                        };

                    //development env.
                        sass.dev = {
                            options: { 
                                style: "expanded", 
                                lineNumber: true,
                            }
                            , files: {
                                "<%= src.devFolder %>" : "<%= src.sassMain %>"
                            }
                        };


                    //grunt serve ===============================
                    config.connect = {
                         server: {
                          options: {
                            port: 8000,
                            base: {
                              path: 'SITE',
                              options: {
                                index: 'index.html',
                                maxAge: 300000
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    };


    //Register custom tasks ===============================
    grunt.registerTask('default',['dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['concat:dev','sass:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('dist',['concat:dev','sass:dist']);



    //General setup ===============================
    grunt.initConfig(config);
    tasks.forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the `grunt-contrib-connect` plugin by itself, you'll need the property `keepalive` set to **true** in your grunt config:

```
config.connect = {
    server: {
        options: {
            port: 8000,
            keepAlive: true,
            base: {
                path: 'SITE',
                options: {
                    index: 'index.html',
                    maxAge: 300000
                }
            }
        }   
    }
};
```

**Worth Noting** if you want to use your connect config as part of a chain of tasks, `keepAlive` will need to be set to false, otherwise tasks after `connect` task won't run.  You can also keep `connect` running by pairing it with the `watch` task w/o using the `keepAlive` option.